# What's the "NEW ZEND FRAMEWORK 1 SECURITY VULNERABILITY"?

Tags: magento-enterprise, security, patches

Today we learned that Magento has a new vulnerability. They call it **NEW ZEND FRAMEWORK 1 SECURITY VULNERABILITY**.

It's described as follow [here](https://magento.com/security/news/new-zend-framework-1-security-vulnerability):

> To protect your site from this vulnerability, you should immediately
>   check your mail sending settings. Go to the system settings used to
>   control the “Reply to” address for emails sent from your Magento
>   store:
>
> **Magento 1**: System-> Configuration-> Advanced-> System-> Mail Sending
>   Settings-> Set Return-Path
>
> **Magento 2**: Stores-> Configuration-> Advanced-> System-> Mail Sending
>   Settings-> Set Return-Path
>
> If “Set Return-Path” is set to “Yes,” and your server uses Sendmail,
>   then your store is vulnerable to this exploit. Enterprise Cloud
>   Edition customers do not need to worry about this issue. We’ve already
>   checked your configuration and you are not at risk.

**Currently I have settings for `Set Return-Path` as `Specified` in my EE.**

Magento suggests

> Enterprise Cloud Edition customers do not need to worry about this issue

and also

> set it to NO

I am a little confused what to do till the patch arrives.

**Am I vulnerable?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enterprise Edition != Enterprise Cloud Edition

I assume Cloud Edition customers are either not affected by the exploit because they do not use sendmail or Magento changed the configuration for them:

> We’ve already checked your configuration and you are not at risk.

### The following holds true for CE 1.x as well as EE 1.x

If you use sendmail, do as suggested by Magento and configure the return path setting to "No". If you don't know if you use sendmail for emails, you probably use it, as it is the default.

### Is "specified" secure?

I had a look at the core to see where this setting is used. The relevant code is in [Mage_Core_Email_Template](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/d48bebc211cc216aaf78bdf25d7f0b0143d6333b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php#L394-L405):

```
$setReturnPath = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SENDING_SET_RETURN_PATH);
switch ($setReturnPath) {
    case 1:
        $returnPathEmail = $this->getSenderEmail();
        break;
    case 2:
        $returnPathEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SENDING_RETURN_PATH_EMAIL);
        break;
    default:
        $returnPathEmail = null;
        break;
}
```

(1) is "yes", (2) is "specified", and 0 (default) is "no"

The only setting where user input can be used, is "yes". So if you trust your shop admins with access to the system configuration, "specified" is okay too: it takes the address from a constant configured value.

There is one other occurence of the configuration, in [Mage_Newsletter_Model_Template](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/d409dff20e992e97546568974399c456958299f9/app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Template.php#L313-L315):

```
if (Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::XML_PATH_SENDING_SET_RETURN_PATH)) {
    $this->getMail()->setReturnPath($this->getTemplateSenderEmail());
}
```

Here, "specified" is treated the same way as "yes", but the newsletter sender email does not come from untrusted user input, so the same as above applies.

## Magento 2.x

Currently, the "return path" setting is not used anywhere in Magento 2.

Here is a bug report: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6146

Luckily, the bug has not been fixed yet, so Magento 2 without extensions is not affected by the exploit.

Comment: I can't comment because I just joined. I have the same issue but I'm on CE. The dropdown has 3 options: Yes, No, and Specified. Is Specified safe or should it be changed to No?

Comment: When "No" - this completely shuts down delivery of email by the store. Emails are sent, but regarded as spam on the side of person who receives the email. 

I'll be testing specified right now to see what happens.

Comment: From what I'm reading this header is just used for "Bounced" emails. Some servers use it, some dont. Its just weird that it's some kind of requirement for spam filtering.

Comment: yeah looks like Specifying the email address works. There are no bounced emails when you hardcode it to one address. Thanks @fschmengler. I have not tested if this nullifies the threat, but from what Fabian posted here it looks like there  hardcoding it like this will solve the issue temporarily.

Comment: What actually `Set Return-Path` does? And also when I set it to `NO`, I am still able to receive email from the site. Does this mean I am not using it?

Comment: ^^^ i found this 

"The Sender header is used to identify in the message who submitted it. This is usually the same as the From header, which is who the message is from. However, it can differ in some cases where a mail agent is sending messages on behalf of someone else."

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367358/whats-the-difference-between-sender-from-and-return-path

I set mine to bounce@domain.com...so far no bounces or issues when looking through the mail logs

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe.

I've received this message from Magento Support

> I've been informed that using "Specified" from a security standpoint
>   is safe, however if the email address is not correctly set up on the
>   server it might end up as spam.
>
> You can go ahead and use it as long as you've correctly setup the
>   email address used.